# Реализовать загрузку ОС Линукс из GRUB с выводом на экран сообщения

Tags: linux, grub

Как реализовать загрузку ОС Линукс из GRUB с выводом на экран сообщения "Hello"?

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, о чём именно речь (как вы представляете желаемое). внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: когда вы хотите, чтобы появилось сообщение: до показа меню, после или вместо? в каком виде вы хотите выводить сообщение: в виде текста или в виде картинки-заставки? опишите, пожалуйста, как вы представляете желаемое (весь процесс загрузки до старта x-сервера или запуска login).

Comment: В виде текста, после меню.  Точно не знаю, как это должно происходить, я новичок (дали такое задание).